# Importing integer codes with leading zeros as strings from CSV

Tags: import, csv-format

Importing CSV seems to automatically cast to integer what are supposed to be integer codes.

This causes problems when some codes have a prefix of a variable number of "0" and have to be matched verbatim. Import casts say "007" to integer 7.

Is there a way to suggest hints on a column by column basis? If not in CSV some alternative tabular format?

**EDIT**

Edited example to show that some columns are numeric and should remain so on import. The suggested  "Numeric"-> False, is a global option

```
Export["~/Desktop/test.csv", {{"481", 1}, {"064", 2}}, "CSV"]
```

Then, one of 2 bad things happen:

```
Import["~/Desktop/test.csv"]
```

> {{481, 1}, {64, 2}}

Or

```
Import["~/Desktop/test.csv", "Numeric" -> False] // FullForm
```

> ```
> List[List["481","1"],List["064","2"]]
> ```

Comment: Use the `"Numeric"` option: `Import["test.csv", "Numeric" -> False]`. You can find that in the "Options" section of the [documentation for the CSV format](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/CSV.html).

Comment: @MarcoB, thanks but need that option on a column by column basis as in indicated in the Q. I've edited the example to highlight this.

Comment: use `Numeric->False` , then use `ToExpression` to fix the things that are numbers.  eg: `MapAt[ToExpression, Import["test.csv", "Numeric" -> False], {All, 2 ;;}] `

Comment: Use `SemanticImport` with specified column types:
https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SemanticImport.html

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to import your CSV data with `Import`, you need to import each line as a list of strings and then post-process the the data to get the from you want.

```
path = "~/Desktop/test.csv";
data1 = Import[path, "Numeric" -> False]
```

> `{{"481", "1"}, {"064", "2"}}`

```
{#1, ToExpression[#2]} & @@@ data1
```

> `{{"481", 1}, {"064", 2}}`

Alternatively, you can use `SemanticImport`, giving it specifications on how to handle each column.

```
data2 = SemanticImport[path, {"String", "Number"}, "Rows"]
```

> `{{"481", 1}, {"064", 2}}`